# PHP Compare two arrays multidimensional and simple

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

**I have two arrays**

```
$matchingskusarr = Array( 0 => Array(1235 => 171), 1 => Array(1235 => 172),2 => Array(180 => 200),3 => Array(180 => 807),4 => Array(125 => 200),5 => Array(131 => 200)) ;
```

$ordersku = array(0=>807, 1=>200,2=>171,3=>172);

```
function yourMatch($orderskusarr, $matchingskusarr) { 
    $columns = [];  
    foreach ($matchingskusarr as $array) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            //Column already tested just continue
            if(isset($columns[$key])) {
                continue;
            }
            //New column we need to check if it matches our $skus
            $columns[$key] = array_column($matchingskusarr, $key);
            if($columns[$key] == $orderskusarr) {
                return [$key => $columns[$key]];                    
            } 
            else
            {           
                return $columns;            
            } 
        }   
    }       
    }

print_r(yourMatch($orderskusarr, $matchingskusarr));
```

** My function does not return correct result
result should be **

```
Array(1235 => Array(0 => 171,1 => 172),180 => Array(0 => 803,1 => 200);
```

Comment: Do you want the diff between them?

Comment: what is the basis of your output?

Comment: line `foreach ($array as $key => $value);` does nothing

Comment: None of the values in your _correct result result should be_ are in your `$matchingskusarr` or `$skus` array.

Comment: @splash58 It sets `$key` to the last key in `$array`, right? (Seemingly in direct opposition to the comment above it.)

Comment: Is it just me, or is it difficult to determine what this is supposed to do?

Comment: @Don'tPanic If not your nik, I would have panicked  because  do not understand anything :)

Comment: Sorry By mistaken i have posted wrong values in array ,I apologise  my mistake I need to compare two arrays $matchingskusarr and $skus and if values of array $skus  like 807 and 200 found in array $matchingskusarr  with same keys in $matchingskusarr  then form new array with same key like 1235 => Array(0 => 171,1 => 172)  and   180 => Array(0 => 807,1 => 200)
as you can see that 171,172 are present in array with same key 1235 and 807,200 present with same key 180 AND values are present in $skus

Comment: My aim is two comapre two arrays and find match and result needed for example Array(1235 => Array(0 => 171,1 => 172),180 => Array(0 => 803,1 => 200); 

So please help me to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right what you want to achieve, this may work for you.
Please note that the values may repeat in the output if they are found twice in the `$matchingskuarr`, e.g. 200. To avoid it (do you want to?) you'll need to store an index of unique values in another variable.

```
$matchingskusarr = Array( 0 => Array(1235 => 171), 1 => Array(1235 => 172),2 => Array(180 => 200),3 => Array(180 => 807),4 => Array(125 => 200),5 => Array(131 => 200)) ;
$ordersku = array(0=>807, 1=>200,2=>171,3=>172);

$columns = [];
$uniqueSku = [];
foreach ($matchingskusarr as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        // Check for duplicity.
        if (in_array($value, $uniqueSku)) {
            continue;
        }
        // If the $value is contained in $ordersku, save it for output.
        if (in_array($value, $ordersku)) {
            // Initialize the array.
            if (!isset($columns[$key])) {
                $columns[$key] = [];
            }
            // Store the value found.
            $columns[$key][] = $value;
            $uniqueSku[] = $value;
        }
    }
}    
print_r($columns);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [1235] => Array
        (
            [0] => 171
            [1] => 172
        )

    [180] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [1] => 807
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks  jirka for your code you are correct ,But my need is If the value in $ordersku  are present $matchingskusarr  with same keys like 
Array(1235 => Array(0 => 171,1 => 172),180 => Array(0 => 200,1 => 807));
and else
Array(125 => Array(0 => 200),131 => Array(0 => 200));

If you can help it will be grateful ,

Thanks jirka

Comment: Yeah, I don't really understand what you mean but let me assume that you don't want duplicit values in the output - e.g. 200. I added a simple check for duplicity, see updated answer. Please note that storing values into another array and looking it up will increase memory usage. So if you expect thousands or more values to be processed, I'd suggest you find more efficient way.